# ¿ Coma ajustar todo el contenido de una pagina a modo de zoom al tamaño de un iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, asp.net, css3

Necesito ajustar todo el tamaño a modo de zoom de una pagina que es mas grande que el  que lo contiene. la pagina es de 1024 x 800 y el iframe es de 800 x 600.

Tengo puesto este código pero me recorta la zona que sobre pasa el ancho y alto.

```
<iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://mipagina.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Comment: Lo que necesito es que el contenido se ajuste al iFrame y no que el iFrame se ajuste al contenido que es lo que aparece en el ejemplo que me comentas.

Comment: esto de que la pagina es de 1024 x 800 es que no nesesitas que sea responsive?

Comment: la pagina de 1024x800 pasaría a tener el contenido de 800x600 ( El del iframe ) viéndose todo su contenido como se veria en 1024x800 esto quiere decir que el contenido se veria mas pequeño.

Comment: Acabo de probar el enlace de @Kiko_L y es perfecto. El iframe tiene un scroll así que la altura no tiene importancia. El contenido se adapta perfectamente al ancho del iframe.

Comment: No es así, no es lo que pido.  El contenido no se adapta al iFrame ya que el iFrame cambia su alto. Una cosa es que el iFrame se adapte al contenido cambiando su altura o ancho que no es lo que pregunto. Estoy preguntando con un iFrame fijo en ancho y alto ver el contenido adaptado a el. Es decir se tendría que ver como cuando haces un zoom. A ver si me explico mejor en el iFrame no tiene que aparecer las barras de scroll y siendo un iFrame fijo verse toda la pagina en pequeño.

Comment: Tienes razón, entendí mal. Aquí hablan de cómo ajustar el contenido al iframe (la respuesta aceptada está mal). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630308/possible-to-shrink-contents-of-iframe

Comment: Genial @Kiko_L era esto lo que buscaba !